# TextView is overlapping in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am facing 2 issues

1.My text view is overlapping. ID is textView7 and name is OrderStatus

2.I am trying to add the divider using the view it is also not working
NOTE:divider is working i have added the `android:layout_below` property
[image: this is how it is looking]

**MyActivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.lenovo.jdstudio.UpdateOrderStatusActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/updateOrderToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Fname_LinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="First Name "
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Update_FName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_25dp"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Aakash"
                android:textColor="@color/color_3"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|italic" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/Fname_LinearLayout"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Lname_LinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/Fname_LinearLayout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Last Name :"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Update_LName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_25dp"
                android:text="Bidlan"
                android:textColor="@color/color_3"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/Lname_LinearLayout"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/orderStatus_LinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/Lname_LinearLayout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_2dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Order Status"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/orderStatusSpinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_25dp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/orderStatus_LinearLayout"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_LinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/orderStatus_LinearLayout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/UpdateOrderEmail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_25dp"
                android:text="123@gmail.com"
                android:textColor="@color/color_3"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/email_LinearLayout"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/phoneno_LinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/email_LinearLayout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Phone No."
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/update_phoneNumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_25dp"
                android:text="1234567890"
                android:textColor="@color/color_3"
                android:textSize="16sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/phoneno_LinearLayout"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/phoneno_LinearLayout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Photo Description"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Update_photoDesc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_25dp"
                android:text="id passport"
                android:textColor="@color/color_3"
                android:textSize="16sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/UpdateOrderSatatus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:text="Update Order" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/deleteOrder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/UpdateOrderSatatus"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="88dp"
            android:text="Delete Order" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/updateOrderProgress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I tried giving bottom padding first and then bottom margin. it doesn't work.
Thanks for reading the Question.
waiting for the favorable reply...

Comment: which textview is overlapping?

Comment: orderStatus text view

Comment: have you got the reason ? that why it is ovelapping

Comment: Yes i got it. Check my answer and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]**I have made some changes in this XML file Please try this** :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/updateOrderToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Fname_LinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="First Name"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Update_FName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Aakash"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|italic" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Lname_LinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/Fname_LinearLayout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Last Name"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Update_LName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:text="Bidlan"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/orderStatus_LinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/Lname_LinearLayout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Order Status"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/orderStatusSpinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_LinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/orderStatus_LinearLayout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/UpdateOrderEmail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:text="123@gmail.com"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/phoneno_LinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/email_LinearLayout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Phone No."
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/update_phoneNumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:text="1234567890"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/phoneno_LinearLayout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Photo Description"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Update_photoDesc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:text="id passport"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/UpdateOrderSatatus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:text="Update Order" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/deleteOrder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/UpdateOrderSatatus"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="88dp"
            android:text="Delete Order" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/updateOrderProgress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hey can you give me some info about how to send email to the client please

Comment: Which Client ? can you elaborate ?

Comment: can i have your email id bcoz this is not related to this  question

Answer (score 0):

There are too many rows for one screen in a non-scrollable layout. You should add a ScrollView to avoid problems with shorter screens or split the views in several ViewGroups / screens (for example by using some collapsible containers or ViewPager). 
If that is not possible you could set weights to the TextViews' height and use the [auto size text](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html)

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="105dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

Also consider using a layout that is more suitable for the design, such as GridLayout or ConstraintLayout to avoid hard coding the TextView width.